# Idiom for "Ahead of its time"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Is *En avance sur son temps* idiomatic in French as *Ahead of its time* in English? For instance,

> Five Movies with Special Effects Ahead of Their Time.
>
> Cinq films avec effets spéciaux en avance sur leur temps.

Comment: Ici la seule chose à changer c'est que "*with special effects*" se traduit par "*avec **des** effets spéciaux*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is, but note that *Cinq films avec **des** effets spéciaux en avance sur leur temps* sounds really better.

Answer (score 5):

On emploie l'expression « en avance sur son temps » plutôt en parlant d'une personne.

> Cinq films avec des effets spéciaux novateurs.
>   Cinq films aux effets spéciaux d'avant-garde.
>   Cinq films aux effets spéciaux futuristes.

Comment: Je préférerais personnellement ***d'avant-garde*** à ***avant-gardiste*** qui reste bien attaché à un courant artistique particulier... (appartenant d'ailleurs... au passé ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

Bien d'accord avec la contribution de @Destal dans le sens commun.

Rigoureusement et logiquement un peu moins et comme la question vient d'un... mécanicien... :

*etre en avance sur son temps* ne peut, en toute logique, se dire que... bien postérieurement au fait ainsi qualifié.

*être en avance sur son temps* signifie que à t0 donné, un fait prend la valeur qu'il aura à t1 > t0.

Or... qu'en sait-on de la valeur qu'aura ce fait à t1 avant un t2 >= t1 ?

Je semble ergoter par pur plaisir (le plaisir n'en est certes pas exempt) mais je crois cette logique d'importance particulièrement dans le domaine de la **création artistique** dans le cadre de laquelle on peut entendre cette expression.

Car si, dans tout autre cadre, on pourrait admettre que certains faits sont prédictibles, la création artistique déjoue, par nature toute prédiction.

On connaît un cas typique qui est celui des derniers quatuors de Beethoven qui, de son vivant, ont reçu un accueil particulièrement... froid.

Interrogé sur ce fait curieux, Beethoven (habitué aux triomphes) répondra que le public n'a pas compris et que c'est tout à fait normal. Il ne peut pas comprendre. Mais... il comprendra... plus tard!

50 ans plus tard... c'était le triomphe. Magique!

Donc oui, les derniers quatuors de Beethoven étaient bien en avance sur leur temps. Mais... juste... on ne pouvait pas le dire... à moins de 50 ans plus tard! ;-)

Si on accepte donc ce *bémol*... ;-)... je traduirais donc, dans le temps du fait, ce *ahead of its/their time* par ***jamais vu/s***

Answer (score 1):

You could also try rewording the sentence.

Original:

> Five movies with special effects ahead of its time

Reworded:

> Five movies with special effects much more advanced than most in this period.

French:

> Cinq films avec des effets spéciaux beaucoup plus avances que le reste dans cette période.